# CSS ajax new span not updating in internet explorer 10

Tags: css, ajax, internet-explorer, firefox

I have this element on my page:

```
<td class="hb_high" id="aHighBid_1">1,175.00</td>
```

styled with this css:

```
#divcatalog td.hb_high {
   text-align:right;
   padding-right:3px;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#D00;
  }
```

After an ajax request, not only do the contents change, but the color also needs to change

My ajax response adds:

```
<span class="hb_Ajax">1,625.00</span>
```

so the entire element looks like:

```
<td id="aHighBid_1" class="hb_high">
  <span class="hb_Ajax">1,625.00</span>
</td>
```

which uses this css definition:

```
 span.hb_Ajax {
   text-align:right;
   font-size:1.5em;
   padding-right:3px;
   font-weight:bold;
   color:#000;
  }
```

This works in firefox changing the color to black and increasing the text size.
In IE10, the value changes, but the color/size does not.

Is there an IE workaround ?
Am i using the correct approach ?
Is there a better way ?

Comment: Consider providing us a http://jsfiddle.net with your relevant code. It'll be much easier to help you.

Comment: Reposting `Brian Wolfsohn's` comment under a deleted post: @Itay, I appreciate your suggestions.. I have tried to create a jsfiddle, but it works there in both IE and firefox... since this involves ajax and a rather involved script which is inserting a span inside of the original code, I haven't been able to break out a short portion that breaks in jsfiddle.. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm flying very blind here.. :) -- Brian Wolfsohn  (reposted by -->

Comment: @BrianWolfsohn In order to solve your problem, it is necessary to see (at the least) your AJAX code. Although a jsFiddle won't **work** in the normal sense, it will at least allow us to see your full code and perhaps spot how to resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `color: #000 !important;` se if that helps.

Comment: Why won't you help him fix his priorities problem instead of using this troublesome `!important` Keyword?

Comment: @Itay Usually I like your answers and comments, but not this time. Why don't you help the OP with a suggestion, rather than criticizing someone else who is? I would give it a shot, but I'm not sure what you mean by the `priorities problem`?

Comment: @gibberish Thanks for the constructive criticism. First, I'll make it clear that I strongly believe using `!important` should be avoided (just google it if you don't know why), especially on answers on SO. This is just a walk around instead of a solution. Second, notice how the OP uses the `#divcatalog td.hb_high` selector which contains an element's ID, an element type and a class. It's a very highly prioritized selector. While the second selector `span.hb_Ajax` doesn't contain an ID and therefor is much weaker, and that's probably why it's not working.

Comment: @Itay I rarely use it. On my current project I had a similar issue with IE and font color in jQuery UI Dialog, `!important! fixed it. Reason I didn't suggest your kind of more specific # and class target is that it didn't help in my case and I wouldn't think it would his either.

Comment: @Itay, It hasn't helped.. Works in fireforx not in IE. I ended up with inline cods instead of css.  `[<span style='color: #D00 font-size:1.25em'>]` and it works in both browsers

Comment: @BrianWolfsohn Too bad you're not listening. If you had posted a jsfiddle with your problem, your problem would have been solved already. We can't see the full picture from your textual description only. And Dejan - I see. All cool

Comment: @Dejan.S This is bugging me, I just wanted to make clear I didn't mean to be rude on my first comment, but it really does sounds bad.

Comment: @Itay - A genteel response, Itay, and thank you for sharing your reasoning. I trust Brian (OP) profits as much from your deductions as I did (and as I usually do from your answers).